# Question about a paper on approximate identities

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am currently reading [this](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2012/386785/) paper on approximate identities of ternary Banach algebras. Assume that $(A, [.,.,.])$ is a ternary Banach algebra. A bounded net $(e_{\alpha}, f_{\alpha})$ is said to be left-bounded approximate identity for $A$ if $\lim_{\alpha}[e_{\alpha}, f_{\alpha},a]=a$ for all $a \in A$. Can someone clarify my following questions on the same paper:

> What is the definition of bounded net? Also at many places in the same paper for instance in Theorem $2.2$, the product $e_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}$ is used. What is the meaning of product in ternary algebra?

All these terms are not explained in paper. Thank you very much in advance!

P.S: Copy of the same question On MSE can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723462/question-about-a-paper-on-approximate-identities).

Comment: Having look briefly at the paper you link to, I also cannot make sense of it, because as you say, they repeatedly seem to use a normal "product" on a ternary Banach algebra, which is of course not defined.  For example, I cannot find a meaning for equation (2.1)

Comment: @MatthewDaws, exactly it’s not clear what they really meant.

Comment: Cross-posted on [Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723462/question-about-a-paper-on-approximate-identities) and now has a very interesting answer...